# Cannot access the specified path or file on the server, verify that you have the necessary security privileges and that the path or file exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and just logged in using SQL Server authentication. When I try to create a database in the SQL Server authentication mode, I get this error:

[image: Cannot access the specified file path.....]

I tried to fix it by allowing privileges to it but all gone in waste. It also doesn't allow me alter privileges of User in the form of granting the access of dbcreator but also went in waste. Please help me anyone here.

Thanks in advance.

[image: user login altering privileges error]

Comment: Sounds like the service account that SQL Server is running under doesn't have access to `E:\`; you'll need to grant it access if that's where you want to create the data files.

Comment: can you please guide me how to grant access to 'E'

Answer (score 0):

> cannot access the specified path or file on the server, verify that
>   you have the necessary security privileges and that the path or file
>   exists

This issue related to a **service account** of the data engine. It has nothing to do with your SQL login and related permissions, like `dbcreator`.

Such a situation can be caused by changing the default data folder to a directory where the SQL Server service account does not enough permissions

So, make sure that the service account has FULL permissions on a folder where the database files to be created.

The service account can be checked/changed using SQL Server Configuration Manager:

[image: SQL Server Configuration Manager]

Comment: but what are the changes i need to do with this area?

Comment: Firstly, start with checking what is the service account of SQL Server, and verifying that it has full permissions on the folder where database creation failed

Comment: There is a shortcut: usage of **bult-in System** account. This can be a solution for a testing labs, but not good for a production grade servers..

Comment: still can't fix the issue

Comment: Another thing is that your default location for a database is a root of the drive (E:). Windows allows writing to root location only to accounts with admin permissions. Have you tried with creating folders on drive E and granting write/read permissions there?

Comment: no i have not changed the location of databases. this is on the default location.

Comment: Have you tried to set an instance service account to built-in->system and then restart the instance?

Comment: Now i have tried using Local service from buit-in services, but it issue still occurs.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnwar,  "Local service" is not the same as the "Local System", right? So, question is: *"Have you tried to set an instance service account to built-in->system and then restart the instance?"*

Comment: I have tried built-in>system also but it doesn't work Bro.

Comment: ok, last tries before giving up, what error message you receive when run T-SQL command: `create database test` and what returns: `SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('dbcreator')`

Answer (score 0):

go to SQL server configuration --> right click on MSSQLSERVER --> Properties --> built-in --> system

and then restart the instance.

this has worked for me.